# How do I use str_replace in an IF statement?

Tags: php

I have an input field that automatically inserts the value of 'www.' before anything the user types. The data in the input field then gets inserted into a table.

Using PHP, I am trying to remove/strip the instance of 'www.' IF an '@' symbol is typed into the input field. I cannot seem to get this to work, looking at what is output in my SQL Table. I'm using an empty variable in $var to replace the 'www.'

Here is my code:

```
if(strpos($_POST['Link'], '@') !== false) {
    $webvar = 'Twitter';
    str_replace('www.', '', $var);
    $link       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '<a href='."'".'https://'.'twitter.com/'.$_POST['Link']."' ".'target='."'".'_blank'."'".'>'.$webvar.'</a>');
}
```

Comment: str_replace probably isn't ideal for this as you would only want to replace www. at the beginning of the string, not throughout it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is unclear but something like this ?

```
if (strpos($_POST['Link'], '@')) {
    $webvar = 'Twitter';
    $link = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '<a href=' . "'" . 'https://' . 'twitter.com/' . str_replace('www.', '', $_POST['Link'])  . "' " . 'target=' . "'" . '_blank' . "'" . '>' . $webvar . '</a>'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should directly assign the value back to the variable (although it's not clear what `$var` is, it sounds like it should be `$_POST['Link']`)

```
$var = str_replace('www.', '', $_POST['Link']);
```

Comment: Exact, str_replace doesn't change the original variable. Also, keep in mind that str_replace is deprecated in newer versions of PHP, you should use preg_replace() instead.

Comment: @Webomatik `str_replace()` isn't deprecated?!

Comment: The variable is
    $link       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '<a href='."'".'https://'.'twitter.com/'.$_POST['Link']."' ".'target='."'".'_blank'."'".'>'.$webvar.'</a>');
}

Comment: You're right @Rizier123, my bad, I confused str_replace with ereg_replace, deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 7